# Extend LVM Volume - How to use parted to extend physical volume?

Tags: partitioning, lvm, parted

I have a cloud server running Ubuntu 14.04 being hosted by fasthosts. I recently upgraded the storage from 100GB to 110GB however when i run `df` i can see this currently isn't being used by the filesystem

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            483M  4.0K  483M   1% /dev
tmpfs            99M  688K   99M   1% /run
/dev/dm-0        99G   87G  7.4G  93% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            494M  8.0K  494M   1% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1       232M   79M  137M  37% /boot
```

I understand i need to extend my physical volumes to use them with LVM

```
$ sudo pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda5
  VG Name               VolGroup00
  PV Size               49.76 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              12738
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          12738
  PV UUID               6Oa34y-MFIr-KFy1-7TUB-liRV-d6vn-qnlWZ9

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda6
  VG Name               VolGroup00
  PV Size               50.00 GiB / not usable 3.97 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              12799
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          12799
  PV UUID               DIwQMv-vFaL-dih4-OE2R-bwRp-XfUd-etDeWo
```

I tried extending my second partition to the end of the disk space to use it with LVM but this hasn't worked.

```
(parted) print free
Model: Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 118GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
        32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB            Free Space
 1      1049kB  256MB   255MB   primary   ext4         boot
        256MB   257MB   1048kB            Free Space
 2      257MB   118GB   118GB   extended
 5      257MB   53.7GB  53.4GB  logical                lvm
 6      53.7GB  107GB   53.7GB  logical                lvm
        107GB   118GB   10.6GB            Free Space
        118GB   118GB   112MB             Free Space
```

Should i create a new partition or is there a way to extend partition 6 to use the extra space?

output to `pvs;vgs;lvs`

```
$ sudo pvs && sudo vgs && sudo lvs
  PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda5  VolGroup00 lvm2 a--  49.76g    0
  /dev/sda6  VolGroup00 lvm2 a--  50.00g    0
  VG         #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  VolGroup00   2   1   0 wz--n- 99.75g    0
  LV       VG         Attr      LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  LogVol00 VolGroup00 -wi-ao--- 99.75g
```

Comment: I can't use a GUI I just have terminal access unfortunately.

Comment: Better!  what's the output to `pvs;vgs;lvs` (run as root)

Comment: Hi @Fabby, Thanks for your help. I added the output to the question above.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little late but I want to explain as a RedHat user.
You should create a physical volume with the `pvcreate`command, in your case

```
    $ pvcreate /dev/sda7
```

You have `/dev/sda6` as your last physical volume which means you can create new physical volume as`/dev/sda7`.
and then extend your volume group to have free space with `vgextend VolumeGroupName /created/part` and `vgdisplay VolumeGroupName` to check free space

```
    $ vgextend VolGroup00 /dev/sda7 
    $ vgdisplay VolGroup00
```

and then you can extend your lvm partition(/dev/sda6).

[Physical volumes are combined into volume groups and volume groups are divided up into logical volumes.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/pdf/configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-8-Configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes-en-US.pdf)
To extend logical volume you need to have free space in your volume group. To have free space in your volume group you need a free partition which is a physical partition to extend your volume group.

Logical Volume operations are nearly same for lots of distributions.

Comment: This might be a little late :) .... but where did sda7 come from?

Comment: Might be, as I already mentioned :)
explanation for sda7 added.